# The sum of the reciprocal of primeth primes

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

A few days ago, a friend of mine taught me that the sum of the reciprocal of [primeth primes](http://oeis.org/A006450) $$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{31}+\cdots$$
*converges*.

Does anyone know some papers which have a rigorous proof with the convergence value?

Comment: There are only about $20$ primeth primes that have been calculated (see [OEIS A007097](https://oeis.org/A007097)). Obviously, this sum is smaller than the sum of reciprocals of power of $2$, so it would quickly converge. EDIT: Sorry, that's a different sequence (which you might find interesting regardless, so I'll leave this comment here for a few more minutes).

Comment: @barakmanos: You're talking about a different sequence than the author. Yes, the sum of the reciprocals of A007097 converge very quickly, but so do the sum of the reciprocals of A006450 (albeit much more slowly).

Comment: @Charles: Yes, I just noticed (and noted) that.

Comment: Is the convergence value even known?

Comment: @RghtHndSd: See my answer.

Comment: @Charles: That is not an answer to my question, nor the question asked here by the way...

Comment: @RghtHndSd: It gives the value the sum converges to, which seems to be your question. Technically, neither my answer nor Jack's answers the question, which is a reference request -- but both of our answers address the issues mathlove was grappling with. I had hoped my 16+ hour calculation would be of some use to you but if not, sorry!

Comment: @Charles: You seem to not differentiate between an estimate for the sum and the actual value; I find this odd. Are you really satisfied with $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} \approx 1.66493$?

Comment: @RghtHndSd: You're expecting a closed form? I find that extremely unlikely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the value of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{p_{p_i}}$ where $p_{i}$ is the $i$th prime?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430369/what-is-the-value-of-sum-limits-i-1-infty-frac1p-p-i-where-p-i-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a duplicate. We have $p_n\gg n\log n$ by Chebyshev's theorem (or the PNT) hence $$p_{p_n}\gg p_n \log n \gg n\log^2 n$$ and $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$$
is convergent by Cauchy's condensation test.

Comment: - or the integral test, since $\int 1/(t\log^2t)\,dt = -1/\log t+C$

Answer (score 4):

Jack has already shown that the sequence converges. By summing the primeth primes up to $10^{11}$ and taking an integral to cover the missing terms I estimate that the reciprocal sum is about 1.05. The sum up to $10^9$ is 0.9904, the sum up to $10^{10}$ is 0.9960, and the sum up to $10^{11}$ is 1.0005.